# Obtener meses dentro de un rango de fechas en php con el dia 24 se salta el mes

Tags: php, datetime

estoy tratando de obtener los meses en un rango de fecha específico pero al hacer el for con una fecha

> cuando coloco el dia **31** y la otra fecha es **4 menor que 31** se salta
> el mes y no lo cuenta

```
$f1 = new DateTime('2021-10-31');
$f2 = new DateTime('2022-11-4');

$cant_meses = $f2->diff($f1);
$cant_meses = ($cant_meses->format('%y') * 12) // 12 meses por cada año
    + $cant_meses->format('%m')                // Meses de diferencia
    + ceil($cant_meses->format('%d') / 31);    // Un mes más si días no es cero
$listaMeses = array($f1->format('Y-m-d'));

for ($i = 1; $i <= $cant_meses; $i++) {

    $ultimaFecha = end($listaMeses);
    $ultimaFecha = new DateTime($ultimaFecha);
    $nuevaFecha = $ultimaFecha->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
    $nuevaFecha = $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d');

    array_push($listaMeses, $nuevaFecha) ;

}
var_dump($listaMeses);
```

Comment: Ayudaría tener ejemplo(s) del resultado esperado.

Comment: ejemplos esperado puedo escoger cualquier fecha de f1 hasta el f2 hay incluye tambien el dia para hacer la busqueda

Comment: Esos serían ejemplos de las entradas y podemos imaginarnos muchas; pero no me queda claro el resultado esperado, dices que de "los meses en un rango" "se salta el mes" ¿Cuál mes? ¿el primero, el segundo, el último?. Ya que la descripción no es clara, ayudaría un -por lo menos- ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: Esta pregunta no se entiende. No hay ningún enunciado que explique exactamente qué es lo que quieres lograr. Pasas a describir el error directamente sin decir: *necesito hacer tal y tal cosa, espero tal resultado, pero lo que obtengo es este resultado erróneo.*

Answer (score 3):

Solo te falta considerar los días de diferencia, porque el resultado de `var_dump($f2->diff($f1));` te da esto:

```
object(DateInterval)[4]
  public 'y' => int 1    // Multiplicar por 12
  public 'm' => int 0    // Cero meses
  public 'd' => int 11   // Hay que tomar en cuenta los días
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'f' => float 0
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 1
  public 'days' => int 376
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

La solución es muy sencilla, se deben agregar 12 meses por cada año y, si hay al menos un día de diferencia, se debe agregar otro mes, solo sumando `ceil($cant_meses->format('%d') / 31)`:

```
$f1 = new DateTime('2021-10-24');
$f2 = new DateTime('2022-11-4');

// Analizar diferencia de días
$d1 = (int) $f1->format('%d');
$d2 = (int) $f2->format('%d');
// Si el resultado es menor, agregar un mes
$plusMonth = (($d1 - ($d2) < 0) ? 1 : 0;


$cant_meses = $f2->diff($f1);
$cant_meses = ($cant_meses->format('%y') * 12) // 12 meses por cada año
    + $cant_meses->format('%m')                // Meses de diferencia
    + $plusMonth;                              // Un mes más, de acuerdo a diferencia de días
$listaMeses = array($f1->format('Y-m-d'));

for ($i = 1; $i <= $cant_meses; $i++) {

    $ultimaFecha = end($listaMeses);
    $ultimaFecha = new DateTime($ultimaFecha);
    $nuevaFecha = $ultimaFecha->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
    $nuevaFecha = $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d');

    array_push($listaMeses, $nuevaFecha) ;

}
var_dump($listaMeses);
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=14)
  0 => string '2021-10-24' (length=10)
  1 => string '2021-11-24' (length=10)
  2 => string '2021-12-24' (length=10)
  3 => string '2022-01-24' (length=10)
  4 => string '2022-02-24' (length=10)
  5 => string '2022-03-24' (length=10)
  6 => string '2022-04-24' (length=10)
  7 => string '2022-05-24' (length=10)
  8 => string '2022-06-24' (length=10)
  9 => string '2022-07-24' (length=10)
  10 => string '2022-08-24' (length=10)
  11 => string '2022-09-24' (length=10)
  12 => string '2022-10-24' (length=10)
  13 => string '2022-11-24' (length=10)
```

Comment: no funciona y otra cosa es que me di cuenta es que toma el año 2021 deberia tomar el año 2022 y los meses deferencia

Comment: @steven, cierto, no se estaban tomando en cuenta los años; ya está corregida la respuesta.

Comment: Listo Muchas gracias

Comment: cuando se ubica en la fecha 31 me salta al mes siguiente el mismo problema que tengo solo que antes era del 24 a hora es del 31

Comment: @steven, listo, solo faltaba analizar la diferencia de días para mantenerse en el mismo mes cuando sea conveniente

Comment: mira que si colocas el dia 31 del mes de marzo hasta el 6 de junio me pasa a el 6 de julio

Answer (score 1):

si tienen una mejor forma lo dicen
Ya pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera :

```
$fi = new DateTime('2021-05-31');

$ff = new DateTime('2021-06-06');


$f1= new DateTime($fi->format('Y-m'));
$f2=new DateTime($ff->format('Y-m'));
$f2 = $f2->modify( '+1 month' );
$intervalo = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($f1, $intervalo, $f2);
$meses = 0;
 foreach($periodo as $mes) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date = $fi;
    if($date->format('Y-m')!=$mes->format('Y-m')){
            $date=$mes; 
         
        }
    echo $date->format('y-m-d'). "\n";
    $meses++;
 }

21-05-31
21-06-01
```

Comment: Pero si la diferencia entre `21-05-31` y `21-06-01` es un día. ¿Es ese el resultado esperado? Tendrías que explicar -en la pregunta- esa lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta:

```
<?php
$f1 = new DateTime('2021-10-31');
$f2 = new DateTime('2022-11-4');

$f2 = $f2->modify( '+1 month' );
$intervalo = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($f1, $intervalo, $f2);
$meses = 0;
foreach($periodo as $mes) {
    $meses++;
}

var_dump( $meses );
```

EDIT: para obtener los meses del periodo:

```
<?php
$f1 = new DateTime('2021-10-31');
$f2 = new DateTime('2022-11-4');

$f2 = $f2->modify( '+1 month' );
$intervalo = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($f1, $intervalo, $f2);
$meses = 0;
$meses_str = [];
foreach($periodo as $mes) {
    array_push($meses_str,$mes->format("Y/m"));
    $meses++;
}

    var_dump($meses_str);
    var_dump( $meses );
```

Resultado:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "2021/10"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2021/12"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "2022/01"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "2022/02"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "2022/03"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "2022/04"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "2022/05"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "2022/06"
  [8]=>
  string(7) "2022/07"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "2022/08"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "2022/09"
  [11]=>
  string(7) "2022/10"
  [12]=>
  string(7) "2022/11"
  [13]=>
  string(7) "2022/12"
}


int(14)
```

Comment: y como obtengo el mes en cada periodo?

Comment: Listo, edité la respuesta con otro ejemplo.

Comment: $f1 = new DateTime('2021-5-31');
$f2 = new DateTime('2021-6-6');
no funciona pasa a el mes 07

Comment: Quieres que  si hay una fecha como las que mencionas, cuente uno o dos meses?
Puesto que del mes 5 al 6 en si solo es un mes.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con algo asi:

```
    $f1 = new DateTime('2021-10-31');
    $f2 = new DateTime('2022-11-4');

    $y1=$f1->format('Y');
    $y2=$f2->format('Y');
    $m1=$f1->format('m');
    $m2=$f2->format('m');

    $listaMeses=array();
    $m=$m1;
    for ($i=$y1; $i <=$y2 ; $i++) {
        if($i==$y2){
            while ($m <= $m2) {
                $Mes=str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $Fecha_actual= $i."-".$Mes."-01";
                array_push($listaMeses, $Fecha_actual) ;
                $m++;
            }
        }else{
            while ($m <= 12) {
                $Mes=str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $Fecha_actual= $i."-".$Mes."-01";
                array_push($listaMeses, $Fecha_actual) ;
                $m++;
            }
        }
        $m=1;
    }
    var_dump($listaMeses);
```

Comment: Explica brevemente qué hace este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.